# JQuery - Persisting a value across postbacks

Tags: jquery, http, postback

New to jQuery...

I have a hidden value on an aspx page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenLabel1" runat="server" value="hidden value"/>
```

When a button is pressed, I do this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loc + "/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#Label1").text(msg.d);
            $("#hiddenLabel1").val(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

In my code behind, I do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Label1.Text = hiddenLabel1.Value;
}
```

After I press the button, the date/time is returned by the GetDate method and I show it in Label1 and attempt to save it in hidden field hiddenLabel1. I view source and expect to see the value of msg.d as the value for hiddenLabel1. However, it has its original value.

Three questions: 1) Why doesn't the hidden field show a new value? 2) Is it in fact true, as it seems to me, that unlike changing the text of a label in a C# code behind page and have it retain its new value across a post back, it is not possible to do the same if the text is changed in a jQuery function? 3) If true, is my approach to use a hidden field to keep and then load the new value workable?

Comment: Upon clicking the button, are you seeing any errors in the console ouput of your browser? Like Firebug for FF.

Comment: To assist you with #2 and 3: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: The source wont change. If you inspect the element in chrome or with firebug you may see a change reflected.

Comment: @DevlshOne. Not sure what I did, but my plan is now working as I intended. I simply set the value of a label with the date/time, and also save it in the hidden field. Upon the next postback, in the page load method, I restore the value of the label. Is there a reason I should use .data() instead? Thanks for the help, btw.

Answer (score 0):

When doing "view source" the vaule will not be updated, but if you inspect it in a DOM inspector (e.g. IE dev tools) you  will see the updated value

A more old school way of verifying it is to do `alert($("#hiddenLabel1").val());` right after it has been assigned

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loc + "/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#Label1").text(msg.d);
            $("#hiddenLabel1").val(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

Short version --

```
$.post(loc + '/GetDate',{},function(msg) {
            $("#Label1").text(msg.d);
            $("#hiddenLabel1").val(msg.d);
        }, 'json');
```

Comment: Just showing you this abbreviated version because you said you were new to jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I just modified my js file in Visual Studio to the short version, but upon running again, the old version was still used!?